# MBP.hideUrlBar(); Boilerplate Mobile

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-safari, html5boilerplate

Im using The HTML Mobile Bolierplate and im trying to get the URL Address bar to hide using:

```
<script src="/static/js/helper.js"></script>
<script>
  MBP.hideUrlBar();
</script>
```

But it's not working, the helper.js loads okay. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting until the DOM's load event is fired is always a good practice before running UI manipulating code.

For novice users:
jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {
  MBP.hideUrlBar();
});
```

Zepto:

```
Zepto(function() {
  MBP.hideUrlBar();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For guys coming from Google, I think the MBP.hideUrlBar() function needs a little bit explanation on how to use it. I took time to make it works on Android (native browser only, Chrome can't hide his address bar) and iOS :

1. First, your page **NEEDS to have a scrollbar** (it means that your website must NOT be `html,body height:100%`)
2. If you want your website to be 100% (which was my case) you will need to calculate manually the height to add to html,body to be sufficient to hide entirely the scrollbar (this mean that we need to know the height of the address bar...)
3. If you want the MBP function to works on load event, use MBP.hideUrlBarOnLoad(). Beware, it will only works on load event, not on every resize (orientation changes). You will have something like that in your resize function :

   ```
   function resize(){
     firstLoadOfThePage ? MBP.hideUrlBarOnLoad() : MBP.hideUrlBar()
   }
   ```

   (assuming that `firstLoadOfThePage` is a tag to know when it is the first load of the page (first call of resize function)

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
```

to hide the address bar.